# Pass a variable from .jsp page to .js

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, jsp

I am  working on a .jsp page where depending on what header comes from a  request it appears a different div from a .js file
I add a second header and I would like

```
if (info.getLightHeader()!=null)
```

the

```
<div id="lightHeader" class="juices">
```

to appear(the code will be at the .js file)

Is this possible to be?Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jsp script tags inside javascript:

```
<%
String paramLightHeader = "";

if (info.getLightHeader()!=null){

  paramLightHeader=info.getLightHeader();
}
%>
```

use the variable in javascript:

Update: as per your provide code you need this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="lightParamHeader" value='<%= paramLightHeader %>' >
        <c:out value="${lightParamHeader}" />
```

Comment: Dear Garry thank you for your help.I had tried to coded before like the way you suggested but i was getting:  "paramLightHeader cannot be resolved at index.jsp"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a separated .js file, you could have a .jsp file with javascript tags.

scripts.jsp

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var foo = '<%= "Hi" %>'
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a JavaScript variable on JSP page it can be used in all js files and you can pass the value using the Expression language.